# Sum unique occurences in a string based on associated number

Tags: r, bash, bioinformatics

I work with single sequence read classification and want to filter based on the quality of classification. However, the output format needs to be changed in order to do this. I have a classification statistics (a score) like below for each read, which represents ["taxonomy":"kmers assigned to that taxonomy" "taxonomy":"kmers assigned to that taxonomy" etc.], and each taxonomy can occur multiple times.

```
classification_stats<-c("3:1 7:4 0:34 3:7 0:27", 
"0:110 561:19 0:37",
"0:3 562:5 0:7 543:55 0:47")

read_ID<-c("read1", "read2", "read3")

df<-data.frame(read_ID, classification_stats)

> df
  read_ID classification_stats
1   read1 3:1 7:4 0:34 3:7 0:27
2   read2 0:110 561:19 0:37
3   read3 0:3 562:5 0:7 543:55 0:47
```

For each read (each row) I want to count the total number of kmers assigned to a taxonomy (in classification_stats), but since each taxonomy occurs multiple times non-consecutively, this becomes more difficult. What it means is that for e.g. read1 taxonomy 3 has 1+7 kmers, taxonomy 7 has 4 kmers and taxonomy 0 has 34 + 27 kmers.

My desired output looks like this, preferably sorted so that tax1 is the taxonomy with the highest number of kmers.

```
  read_ID     classification_stats        tax1 kmer1 tax2 kmer2 tax3 kmer3
  read1       3:1 7:4 0:34 3:7 0:27       0    61    3    8     7    4
  read2       0:110 561:19 0:37           0    147   561  19    NA   NA
  read3       0:3 562:5 0:7 543:55 0:47   0    57    543  55    562  5
```

Either R or bash solutions are interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution in R. Note that I've changed a little bit in `read 3` to test my codes (`543:55` to `543:80`)

#### Input

```
df
  read_ID      classification_stats
1   read1     3:1 7:4 0:34 3:7 0:27
2   read2         0:110 561:19 0:37
3   read3 0:3 562:5 0:7 543:80 0:47
```

#### Code and output

1. Break the `classification_stats` column into separate rows with a white space as the delimiter.
2. Break the resulting column into two, separated by a colon ":".
3. Then create a `unique_tax` column, which contains the number of `tax` in each `read_ID`. This will be used as part of the column name in `pivot_wider` (telling us how many pairs of `kmer` and `tax` should be generated).
4. `group_by(read_ID, tax)` so that everything works on that level
5. `summarise` the `kmer` column to sum up all values under same `read_ID` and `tax`
6. Arrange the data first by `read_ID` then by `kmer`, so that we can use `row_number()` to generate correct index pairs
7. A single `pivot_wider` is enough in this version of code
8. `left_join` to combine the `classification_stats` column
9. Reorder columns to the place you want

```r
library(tidyverse)

left_join(
  df %>% 
    separate_rows(!read_ID, sep = " ") %>% 
    separate(classification_stats, into = c("tax", "kmer")) %>%
    group_by(read_ID, tax) %>%  
    summarize(kmer = sum(as.numeric(kmer))) %>% 
    arrange(read_ID, desc(kmer)) %>% 
    mutate(unique_tax = row_number()) %>% 
    pivot_wider(everything(), names_from = "unique_tax", values_from = c(tax, kmer)),
  df,
  by = "read_ID"
  ) %>% 
  select(read_ID, classification_stats, tax_1, kmer_1, tax_2, kmer_2, tax_3, kmer_3)

# A tibble: 3 × 8
# Groups:   read_ID [3]
  read_ID classification_stats   tax_1 kmer_1 tax_2 kmer_2 tax_3 kmer_3
  <chr>   <chr>                  <chr>  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
1 read1   3:1 7:4 0:34 3:7 0:27  0         61 3          8 7          4
2 read2   0:110 561:19 0:37      0        147 561       19 NA        NA
3 read3   0:3 562:5 0:7 543:80 … 543       80 0         57 562        5
```

Comment: Hmm, seems that columns are sorted based on the value of tax-columns rather than kmer-columns.  Which - by chance - was the same in my example. I would like tax1 to be the taxonomy with the highest number of total kmers.

Comment: @Morten I've modified my code, should work now :)

Answer (score 1):

**solution using data.table**

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df) # make the tibble a data.table

dt <- df[, .(tax_kmer = unlist(str_split(classification_stats, " "))), by = read_ID]
dt[, c("tax", "kmer") := tstrsplit(tax_kmer, ":")]
dt <- dt[, .(kmer = sum(as.numeric(kmer))), by = .(read_ID, tax)]
dt[, order := frankv(kmer, ties.method = "first", order = c(-1L)), by = read_ID]
dt <- dcast(dt, read_ID ~ order, value.var = c("kmer", "tax"), sep = "")
setcolorder(dt, c("read_ID", paste0(c("tax", "kmer"), rep(1:((ncol(dt)-1)/2), each = 2))))
```

**results**

```
dt
#    read_ID tax1 kmer1 tax2 kmer2 tax3 kmer3
# 1:   read1    0    61    3     8    7     4
# 2:   read2    0   147  561    19 <NA>    NA
# 3:   read3    0    57  543    55  562     5
```

**data**

```
classification_stats <- c(
  "3:1 7:4 0:34 3:7 0:27",
  "0:110 561:19 0:37",
  "0:3 562:5 0:7 543:55 0:47"
)
read_ID <- c("read1", "read2", "read3")
df <- tibble(read_ID, classification_stats)
```

**Breaking down the code**

`dt <- df[, .(tax_kmer = unlist(str_split(classification_stats, " "))), by = read_ID]`

Here we create a new table for your output and make sure every row contains one of your "tax:kmer" pairs for each of your ID groups.

`dt[, c("tax", "kmer") := tstrsplit(tax_kmer, ":")]`

Here we split your tax_kmer pairs in two different columns to hold the tax value and the kmer value.

`dt <- dt[, .(kmer = sum(as.numeric(kmer))), by = .(read_ID, tax)]`
Sum up the kmer values for each of the tax-ID combination.

`dt[, order := frankv(kmer, ties.method = "first", order = c(-1L)), by = read_ID]`

The most safe way to determine the order which defines what tax becomes tax1, tax2, etc. is using a rank number on your kmer sum (-1 ranks from high to low) which I store in the column "order"

`dt <- dcast(dt, read_ID ~ order, value.var = c("kmer", "tax"), sep = "")`

dcast is the data.table variant of "pivot_wider" and note we use order to dcast on and use the values from kmer and tax.

`setcolorder(dt, c("read_ID", paste0(c("tax", "kmer"), rep(1:((ncol(dt)-1)/2), each = 2))))`

Since our dcast procedure orders your table columns with id, then all tax columns and then all kmer columns we dynamically set the order as you prefer. We look at the total number of columns (we do not know in advance how many tax we find right?) and substract one for the ID, by definition we divide it by 2 as it are alternating pairs of tax/kmer. this creates this vector `[1] "read_ID" "tax1"    "kmer1"   "tax2"    "kmer2"   "tax3"    "kmer3"` and that is exactly the order of columns we want to set.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

classification_stats <- c(
  "3:1 7:4 0:34 3:7 0:27",
  "0:110 561:19 0:37",
  "0:3 562:5 0:7 543:55 0:47"
)

read_ID <- c("read1", "read2", "read3")

df <- tibble(read_ID, classification_stats)

df %>%
  separate_rows(classification_stats, sep = " ") %>%
  separate(classification_stats, into = c("tax", "kmer")) %>%
  type_convert() %>%
  arrange(-kmer) %>%
  nest(tax) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  unnest(data) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = c(kmer, tax))
#> Warning: All elements of `...` must be named.
#> Did you want `data = tax`?
#> 
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> cols(
#>   read_ID = col_character(),
#>   tax = col_double(),
#>   kmer = col_double()
#> )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 27
#>   read_ID kmer_1 kmer_2 kmer_3 kmer_4 kmer_5 kmer_6 kmer_7 kmer_8 kmer_9 kmer_10
#>   <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 read2      110     NA     NA     37     NA     NA     19     NA     NA      NA
#> 2 read3       NA     55     47     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      7       5
#> 3 read1       NA     NA     NA     NA     34     27     NA      7     NA      NA
#> # … with 16 more variables: kmer_11 <dbl>, kmer_12 <dbl>, kmer_13 <dbl>,
#> #   tax_1 <dbl>, tax_2 <dbl>, tax_3 <dbl>, tax_4 <dbl>, tax_5 <dbl>,
#> #   tax_6 <dbl>, tax_7 <dbl>, tax_8 <dbl>, tax_9 <dbl>, tax_10 <dbl>,
#> #   tax_11 <dbl>, tax_12 <dbl>, tax_13 <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

And this here counts how often a kmer or taxon occurred for each read:

```
df %>%
  separate_rows(classification_stats, sep = " ") %>%
  separate(classification_stats, into = c("tax", "kmer")) %>%
  type_convert() %>%
  arrange(-kmer) %>%
  nest(-tax) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  unnest(data) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = c(kmer, tax), values_fn = length)
#> Warning: All elements of `...` must be named.
#> Did you want `data = -tax`?
#> 
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> cols(
#>   read_ID = col_character(),
#>   tax = col_double(),
#>   kmer = col_double()
#> )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 13
#>   read_ID kmer_1 kmer_2 kmer_3 kmer_4 kmer_5 kmer_6 tax_1 tax_2 tax_3 tax_4
#>   <chr>    <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 read2        2     NA      1     NA     NA     NA     2    NA     1    NA
#> 2 read3        3      1     NA     NA      1     NA     3     1    NA    NA
#> 3 read1        2     NA     NA      2     NA      1     2    NA    NA     2
#> # … with 2 more variables: tax_5 <int>, tax_6 <int>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Very close to what I would like, which is that tax1 is the taxonomy with the highest number of kmers for each of the reads. Meaning that tax1 is not necessarily the same for read1 and read2

Comment: `nest(-c(tax, read_ID))` will make a taxon unique to a read but I think this is not what you want, because the same taxon can be in multiple reads...

Comment: Not sure how to implement this. Yes, but say that taxon 9 is in read11 and read12, they dont have to be in the same tax-column afterwards if that is not the correct order. E.g., the column "tax1" will have different values across the reads.